# Как добавить таблицу в условное место в документе docx

Tags: python, docx

Обычно для вставки контента, я использую ключи {{some_data}} в документе.Сейчас потребовалось сформировать таблицу и вставить её по ключу в документ, но к сожалению так не получается, пытался через различные костыли это сделать, но тоже не получается, результат совсем печальный, мучаюсь уже 5 дней...

Вот пример моих изысканий :D В конце я копирую контент после добавления таблиц, но 1 это text, т.е. форматирование идёт нафиг, второе, удалить то что скопировал, значит удалить форматирование вообще всех параграфов.

```
def tablica_dly_groop():
    table_data = [
        ['Б', '1'],
        ['Г', '2'],
        ['О', '3']
    ]

    table = []
    for row in table_data:
        table.append(row)

    return table

def tablica_dly_groop_2():
    table_data = [
        ['Д', '4'],
        ['Л', '5'],
        ['Ы', '6']
    ]

    table = []
    for row in table_data:
        table.append(row)

    return table
#            doc.add_page_break()
def download_file(request):
    tpl = DocxTemplate('media/docok.docx')
    context = {
        'tablica': tablica_dly_groop(),
        'tablica_2': tablica_dly_groop_2(),
    }
    tpl.render(context)

    table_data = context['tablica']
    table_data_2 = context['tablica_2']
    doc = tpl.get_docx()

    # Находим параграф "{{lolkek}}"
    for i, paragraph in enumerate(doc.paragraphs):
        if '{{lolkek}}' in paragraph.text:
            # удаляем параграф и заменяем таблицами
            paragraph.insert_paragraph_before('{{lolkek}}')
            paragraph.clear()
    
            # 1 таблица
            table1 = doc.add_table(rows=len(table_data), cols=len(table_data[0]))
            for row in range(len(table_data)):
                for col in range(len(table_data[0])):
                    table1.cell(row, col).text = str(table_data[row][col])
    
            # новая страница
            doc.add_page_break()
    
            # 2 таблица
            table2 = doc.add_table(rows=len(table_data_2), cols=len(table_data_2[0]))
            for row in range(len(table_data_2)):
                for col in range(len(table_data_2[0])):
                    table2.cell(row, col).text = str(table_data_2[row][col])
    
            # Новая страница
            doc.add_page_break()
    
            # Контент после "{{lolkek}}"
            content = doc.paragraphs[i+1:]
            for new_paragraph in content:
                doc.add_paragraph(new_paragraph)
                paragraph.clear()
            for new_paragraph in content:
                new_paragraph.clear()
            break

    doc.save('output/merge_docx.docx')
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76110646/python-docx-template-construct-word-table-in-python-and-place-into-a-specific-l.